# как вывести текст из двух текстовых файлов

Tags: python

Всем привет, писал код для поиска значений в текстовых файлов, с 1 файлом все работает прелестно, а с двумя код возмущается.

Сам код:

```
search = input('запрос:')
with open('test.txt','test2.txt' encoding='utf-8') as f:

    result = f.read()
    c = result.count(search)
    print(f'Количество совпадений {c}')
    input('Для вывода нажми Enter')
    with open('test.txt','test2.txt' encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for line in f:
            if search in line:
                print(line.strip())
```

Ошибка:

```
 line 2, in <module>                                                                                                             
    with open('test.txt','test2.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:                                                                                         
ValueError: invalid mode: 'test2.txt'
```

Comment: open открывает только один файл. Если нужно обработать несколько - берете цикл и в нем поочередно открываете каждый файл.

Comment: в open 2 аргументом идет мод (r - чтение, w - запись, a - дополнить, x - создать и другие), а мода "text2.txt" не существует. Откройте сначала один файл, потом второй (2 раза вызываете open )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно в одном `with` открыть cразу два файла:

```py
search = input('запрос:')

with open('test.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f1, open('test2.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f2:
    result = f1.read() + f2.read()
    c = result.count(search)
    print(f'Количество совпадений {c}')

input('Для вывода нажми Enter')

with open('test.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f1, open('test2.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f2:
    for f in (f1, f2):
        for line in f:
            if search in line:
                print(line.strip())
```

Answer (score 2):

Как и указали в комментариях, `open` может открывать только один файл. Если необходимо открыть несколько, то можно либо использовать `open` повторно, либо открывать файлы в цикле. Один из вариантов решения прилагаю. Постарался внести минимум изменений в Ваш код.

```py
search = input('запрос:')
c = 0
for filename in ['test.txt', 'test2.txt']:
    with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as f:
        result = f.read()
        c = c + result.count(search)
        
print(f'Количество совпадений {c}')
input('Для вывода нажми Enter')
for filename in ['test.txt', 'test2.txt']:
    with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for line in f:
            if search in line:
                print(line.strip())
```